# jQuery validate defaults

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to set some custom defaults for the jQuery validation plugin.

I've tried the following:

```
$.validate.settings.ignore = ":hidden";
```

and

```
$.validate.settings.errorPlacement = function (error, element) {
    if (element.hasClass("removedTitle"))
        error.insertAfter(element.next("img"));
    else
        error.insertAfter(element);
};
```

However, neither of these seem to make any difference. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ":hidden",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("removedTitle"))
            error.insertAfter(element.next("img"));
        else
            error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

Further reading: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults

Comment: I had to drop the semi-colon on line 8, but other than that it worked like a charm.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is it possible to set multiple selector in ignore? I want to ignore hidden and fields that have classes .read-only-state!

Comment: @Murail from the docs: `jQuery's not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this option`, therefore you can use `,` to separate classes, like this: `ignore: ".foo, .bar",`